# android centerCrop scale with top being start aligned

Tags: android

Is there a way to scale an ImageView within dst such that it is almost the equivalent of `centerCrop` except that the result is not centered vertically? I don't want to cut off the top of my image.

Adding a padding of a fixed dp to the `paddingTop` seems to be a hacky way to do it, but I would rather do something that would work for arbitrary phone dimensions.

mathematically it would need to be a paddingTop porportional to the new scaled height of the image before cropping. I am not sure how to do that though, or an alternative cleaner solution of which i am not familiar.

The formula i would like to use is, if my thoughts are correct, is the paddingTop should be `(Y-X)/2` where y is the uncropped scale height in dp and x is the height in dp of the dst view.

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest solution with the advent of `ConstraintLayout` is simply to make a constraint layout which is within the `dst` view, and have it set a dimension ratio on the imageview to be equivalent to the imageviews aspect ratio, and then set the scale type to fitCenter (and it will always fit without needing to center since creating the height to be the images actual height for the width) and then setting top start and end constraints with ˆno bottom constraintˆon the constraint layout. Then assuming the constraint layout takes the available space of dst, it will be cropped by virtue of the fact there is no more vertical room, but it will be aligned top as desired.

e.g.

```
     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:paddingLeft="42dp"
        android:paddingRight="42dp"
        android:paddingBottom="19dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingStart="22dp"
        android:paddingEnd="22dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="855:1293"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```